error of the Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: az.edu.ada.wm2.Farid_Mehdiyev.FaridMehdiyevApplication
I have been trying to solve this problem nearly 3 hours. This is my pom.xml

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.0.4
 

az.edu.ada.wm2
Farid_Mehdiyev
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Farid_Mehdiyev
Demo project for Spring Boot

<java.version>17</java.version>
<spring.boot.version>3.0.4</spring.boot.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf
${spring.boot.version}


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web
${spring.boot.version}

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <version>2.1.214</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.30</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

What i have to change from that do run program without any error?
I am trying to solve error of the Error: Could not find or load main class az.edu.ada.wm2.Farid_Mehdiyev.FaridMehdiyevApplication
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: az.edu.ada.wm2.Farid_Mehdiyev.FaridMehdiyevApplication

Did you try refreshing your libraries by clicking refresh button on Maven? I would also check File - Project Structure - SDKs. Or delete the .build directory and build the project again. If these do not work, right click on the src directory and "Mark Directory as" "Source Root". Good luck.
